# how to iterate over ng-models in input section

Tags: angularjs, json

my application has a side navigation bar that pulls info from the content in the main area. The following is a snapshot of my JSON:

```
{
    "expression": "mithrandir",
    "meaning": [
    {
    "m": "language of the elves",
    "e": ""
    }
    ],
    "example": ["mithrandir is cool"],
    "pronunciation": "",
    "notes": "",
    "meta": {
    "book": "There and back again",
    "author": "Frodo Baggins",
    "tags": ["middle earth", "elves"]}
    },
```

when i click 'edit,' ive been able to get one instance of 'm' and 'e' under 'meaning' property of my json to the sidebar

[sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpmRR.png)

code of the 'meaning' section in sidebar:

```
<md-input-container>
                    <label for="meaning">Meaning</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="meaning" ng-model="classified.meaning[0].m"></textarea>
                    <input type="text" id="example" ng-model="classified.meaning[0].e">
</md-input-container>
```

im unable to figure out how do i iterate in this code to get all instances of 'm' and 'e' under meaning to show?

thanks v much

Comment: Not clear at all what you are trying to do

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: take a look at this plunker  and let me know what else you need  ?https://plnkr.co/edit/Rc4gnOMReFGJQChBJMLK?p=preview

Comment: im sorry... i got the wrong pic of the sidebar.. ive corrected it for reference

Comment: @NV Prasad; thanks but i have more than one 'm' and 'e' under meaning property.https://plnkr.co/edit/6KpppFpW7kfsKOY06t8x?p=preview